# Use react routes depending by condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to implement a logic for routes from my react application. The idea of my routes is next: 
I have 2 pages in my application and 2 roles (user and reviwer) and i want:

1. If user access the application he should be redirected on route -> "/user"
2. If user try to access the route -> "/reviwer" he should be redirected on "/404"
3. If reviwer access the application he should be redirected on route -> "/reviwer"
4. If reviwer try to access the route -> "/user" he should be redirected on "/404"
5. If both users try to access "/login", and they are in application they should be redirected on their personal route

I tried to implement a PrivateRoute for above situation:

```js
const PRoute = ({component:Component,path, ...rest}) => {

    return (
        <Route
            path={path}
            {...rest}
            render={props => (
                localStorage.getItem('mytoken') !== 'undefined' && localStorage.getItem('mytoken')
                ? (
                     localStorage.getItem('role') !== "rev" ?
                         <Route path={'/user'} component={USER}/> :
                         <Route path={'/reviewer'} component={REV}/>

                    ) : (
                   <Redirect to={{pathname:'/login'}}/>
                )
            )}
        />
    );
};
```

...but if i access the application as Reviewer, the condition:

```js
localStorage.getItem('role') !== "rev" ?
<Route path={'/user'} component={USER}/> :
<Route path={'/reviewer'} component={REV}/>...
```

does not work, and i am anyway on "/user" path. 

 **QUESTION**: How to change the code , and to implement the coditions described above?

Answer (score 0):

## Very Simple ‍♂️

First - You should keep your **router clean** so that when you add more routes to it, the routes are very clearly understandable. Like so-

```js
return <Router>
  <Switch>
    <UnAuthRoute path="/login"><LoginPage/></UnAuthRoute>
    <RoleRoute path="/user" role="user"><UserPage/></RoleRoute>
    <RoleRoute path="/reviewer" role="reviewer"><ReviewerPage/></RoleRoute>
  </Switch>
</Router>
};
```

Now, Create two components, one - that will allow you to redirect based on the role and other that will allow only unauthenticated requests to the specified path.

```js
interface Props {
  redirectTo?: string;
  role?: string;
  path: string;
}

export const UnAuthRoute: React.FC<Props> = ({children, redirectTo, path}) => {
  const authenticated = !!localStorage.getItem('mytoken');
  const isReviewer = localStorage.getItem('role') === "rev";

  if (!authenticated) {
    return <Route path={path}>{children}</Route>
  } else {
    return <Redirect to={redirectTo || (isReviewer ? "/reviewer" : "/user")}/>
  }
};

export const RoleRoute: React.FC<Props> = ({children, redirectTo, path, role}) => {
  const authenticated = !!localStorage.getItem('mytoken');
  const allowed = localStorage.getItem('role') === role;

  if (!authenticated) return <Redirect to={redirectTo || "/login"}/>
  else if (allowed) return <Route path={path}>{children}</Route>;
  else return <Redirect to={redirectTo || "/404"}/>
};
```

Comment: why  `<UnAuthRoute path="/login"><LoginPage/></UnAuthRoute>` shold  be first?

Comment: Not necessary to be the first. Put at the last, it should work. Did you give it a try?

Comment: yes, but if i put it last, the routes do not work. After login even the url is changing, but the view not

Comment: i tried to simulate my case in this demo, using your code, but i can't figure out why it does not work   https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-mclaren-9vsvh?file=/src/App.js   i, am redirected on 404

Comment: Working - https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-haze-vj2fp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=light&view=preview